# Smokeping slaves not picking up new jobs automatically

Tags: slave

I have a smokeping server running on Ubuntu 20.04 and 3 slaves on raspbian. Each time a new entry is added in the Targets file and smokeping is restarted, the new measurements start to come in on the master.

On each slave I have to restart the smokeping process too. Is that as intended? I had expected slaves to pick up new jobs automatically.

Does anyone have a solution other than a cron job restarting the process every day?

Thanks,
Dave